# Joomla 2.5 - Add Custom CSS for iPad

Tags: php, html, css, joomla, joomla2.5

I want to load a css file when viewing my joomla website on iPad.

The joomla version I am using is 2.5.

I currently have style-sheets set for browsers e.g. Internet Explorer and Firefox but not sure how to tell the website to load a css file specifically for a device e.g. iPad.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

@isher's answer is a good method, however to import the CSS file, I would do it like so, using Joomla coding standards:

```
<?php
$isiPad = (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad');

if ($isiPad){    
   $doc = JFactory::getDocument(); //only include if line doesn't already exist
   $doc->addStyleSheet (JURI::root() . "template/template-name/ipad-styles.css" );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
<?php
$isiPad = (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad');

if $isiPad;    
  echo "<link href='ipad-styles.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this script and add to your template or custom module (assigned to all page):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){ 
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var regex = new RegExp('ipad',"i"); 
if(userAgent.match(regex)){
    $('<link href="css/ipad.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>').appendTo($('head'));
}});
</script>
```